# Find Descriptor of all messages defined in a proto file

Tags: reflection, protocol-buffers

I need to find all messages described in a proto file.Is there some way to get the descriptor of all messages defined in a proto file??

Comment: At runtime in your program, or using a tool? If at runtime, what language?

Comment: In java at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, given any type `MyType` defined in the file, you can do:

```
MyType.getDescriptor().getFile()
```

This returns a [`Descriptors.FileDescriptor`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.FileDescriptor) which contains information about all types defined in the file.